# Pivoting columns where the values are ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I'm trying to create a pivot table to convert ranges of values. I'm using this sum trick but I've recently learned of the pivot operator and I'm trying to convert the data into a pivot table as the code might be more maintainable that way.
(I've renamed my tables to obscure the data a bit)

```
        select  consultation_id,
                sum(case when current_status_id in (3,4,5,9,10,16,17,18,24,25,26) then 1 else 0 end) [Phase1],
                sum(case when current_status_id in (4,9,10,16,17,18) then 1 else 0 end) [Phase2],
                sum(case when current_status_id in  (10,16,17,18) then 1 else 0 end) [Phase3],
                sum(case when current_status_id = 24 then 1 else 0 end) [Rejected],
                sum(case when current_status_id in (17,18) then 1 else 0 end) [Complete]    
        from subject with (NOLOCK,NOWAIT)
        where ACTIVE_IND = 1
        group by consultation_id
```

Anyone have a suggestion of how to do the conversion?

Edit:
Basically, I'm creating an aggregate of how many subjects made it to a stage of our consultations. This is an aggregate built for a lucene index so that our users can search for particular data. 
here is an example of the raw tabular data and what the output might look like::

```
select  consultation_id,
                sum(case when current_status_id in (3,4,5,9,10,16,17,18,24,25,26) then 1 else 0 end) [Phase1],
                sum(case when current_status_id in (4,9,10,16,17,18) then 1 else 0 end) [Phase2],
                sum(case when current_status_id in  (10,16,17,18) then 1 else 0 end) [Phase3],
                sum(case when current_status_id = 24 then 1 else 0 end) [Rejected],
                sum(case when current_status_id in (17,18) then 1 else 0 end) [Complete]    
        from (values(1588054,11928257,3,1),
                (1588054,11928256,10,1),
                (1588054,11928255,10,1),
                (1588054,11928254,4,1),
                (1588052,11928233,2,1),
                (1588052,11928232,3,0),
                (1588052,11928231,10,1),
                (1588052,11928230,18,1),
                (1588052,11928229,24,1),
                (1588052,11928228,24,1)) subject (consultation_id,subject_id,current_status_id,active_ind)
        where ACTIVE_IND = 1
        group by consultation_id
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data and then the expected result?  It might be easier to convert it to a `PIVOT` from the starting point of the data.  Or even create a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with the sample data.

Comment: I've added a query replacing the real table with a values table with the relevant columns and some sample data.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert this to a `PIVOT`, then my suggestion would be to create a table that contains the `id`'s for each of the `Phases` that you are trying to determine:

```
create table phases
(
  id int,
  name varchar(10)
);
```

Then you will `JOIN` your `subject` table to this new table on the `current_status_id`, this will allow you to then `PIVOT` the data:

```
select s.consultation_id,
  p.name
from subject s
left join phases p
  on s.current_status_id = p.id
where s.ACTIVE_IND = 1
```

So your final query would be:

```
select *
from 
(
  select s.consultation_id,
    p.name
  from subject s
  left join phases p
    on s.current_status_id = p.id
  where s.ACTIVE_IND = 1
) src
pivot
(
  count(name)
  for name in ([Phase1], [Phase2], [Phase3], [Rejected], [Complete])
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/483360/3)

The result matches your existing query:

```
| CONSULTATION_ID | PHASE1 | PHASE2 | PHASE3 | REJECTED | COMPLETE |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|         1588052 |      4 |      2 |      2 |        2 |        1 |
|         1588054 |      4 |      3 |      2 |        0 |        0 |
```

The benefit of using the table is that if you have more `current_status_id`'s that are needed, then you can just add it to the table and they will be counted without needing to change your query.

Comment: The problem is that the phases include multiple statuses and each of the earlier phases includes members in the higher stages. (e.g. phase3 is a subset of both phase 2 and phase 1.)

Comment: @MichaelB you should be able to store the data in a table. It will join based on the `current_status_id` which is assign to each record in the subject table. If there are two entries with different id, it will still be counted.

Comment: I was worried about that approach. I'm concerned that the join against that table might be much larger than the cost of just my seperated sums. The subject table is fairly large about 10mil.

Comment: You would have to test it to see which one will perform better. I did a test on the small sample and I didn't notice a big difference but you have the full dataset, so you will be a better judge on performance.